# How to iterate over MultiDimensional Array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

### I am new to coding and am trying to understand multidimensional arrays in Java.

### Here's my code:

```
String twoD[][] = new String[2][2];

twoD[0][0] = "Hi";

twoD[1][0] = "Hi";
twoD[1][1] = "What's";

twoD[2][0] = "Hi";
twoD[2][1] = "What's";
twoD[2][2] = "Up?";

for (int row = 0; row < twoD.length; row++ ){
    for(int col = 0; col < twoD[row].length; col++){
        System.out.println(twoD[row][col] + "\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

### I am trying to print the following output:

Hi

Hi What's

Hi What's up?

### I've used tutorials to print this:

Hi
null
null

Hi
What's
null

Hi
What's
Up?

### How do I prevent it from printing null? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to create a jagged array, which you could do like

```
String[][] twoD = { { "Hi" }, { "Hi", "What's" }, { "Hi", "What's", "Up" } };
```

And then you probably wanted to `print` (not `println`) in your loop like

```
for (int row = 0; row < twoD.length; row++) {
    for (int col = 0; col < twoD[row].length; col++) {
        System.out.print(twoD[row][col] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Alternatively, with your existing code, you might add a `null` check before you `print` like

```
 if (twoD[row][col] != null) {
     // ...
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer is to use sequential streams.

```
    String twoD[][] = new String[3][3]; // not [2][2]

    twoD[0][0] = "Hi";

    twoD[1][0] = "Hi";
    twoD[1][1] = "What's";

    twoD[2][0] = "Hi";
    twoD[2][1] = "What's";
    twoD[2][2] = "Up?";

    System.out.println(Arrays.stream(twoD)
        .map(oneD -> Arrays.stream(oneD)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```